# Identify Word Number Of String in Excel Cell With VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a cell with the text - 'I made 14 dollars today and 13 dollars yesterday'.
Using VBA in Excel, how do I convert this to - 'I made 11.33 euros today and 10.52 euros yesterday'?

Idea: Based on where the spaces are in the text, VBA could:

```
   a) identify the word order of each word within the cell [ex. '14' is word 
      3, 'dollars' is word 4] 
   b) identify whether the following word was 'dollars' and 
   c) if so, multiply the previous word times the conversion factor of .81.
```

I am stuck on how to put this into code, however. Help, Superusers!

Comment: This wouldn't be hard to do with a formula. Is VBA a necessity?

Comment: A formula solution is okay, yes!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a lookup table of conversion rates, there is no need for VBA.

If you are going to use VBA, my thought would be to "fancy it up" and pull down the most recent conversion rate.  Or you could do that using a specific date, depending on where you get your data from.

Working through this will also expand your knowledge of the possibilities of VBA.

Here's an example which uses the most recent data from a particular web site, but there are plenty out there.  For this one, the api key is free. You'll have to apply for your own.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft winHTTP Services 5.0
'You'll need to install a JSON converter, or perhaps parse the csv output
'You could also parse this simple JSON using Regular Expressions
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Function ConvertInText(S As String) As String
    Dim V As Variant, W As Variant
    Dim DT As Date
    Dim I As Long

V = Split(S, " ")
For I = 0 To UBound(V)
    If V(I) = "Dollars" Then
        V(I) = "Euros"
        V(I - 1) = Format(USDtoEUR(CCur(V(I - 1))), "0.00")
    End If
Next I

ConvertInText = Join(V)
End Function

Private Function USDtoEUR(DOL As Currency) As Currency
    Const myAPI As String = "apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Const sURL As String = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=USD&to_currency=EUR&"
    Dim httpRequest As WinHttpRequest
    Dim strJSON As String, JSON As Object

Set httpRequest = New WinHttpRequest
With httpRequest
    .Open "Get", sURL & myAPI
    .Send
    .WaitForResponse
    strJSON = .ResponseText
End With
Set httpRequest = Nothing

Set JSON = parsejson(strJSON)

USDtoEUR = JSON("Realtime Currency Exchange Rate")("5. Exchange Rate") * DOL

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Great lead - I'll work through this and soon mark if it's the full answer.

Answer (score -2):

*You can try this VBA code through a Command button or as Macro.*

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

i = 8

str1 = Range("A2").Value

str1 = Mid(str1, 1, i - 1) & Replace(str1, "14 dollars today and 13 dollars", "11.33 euros today and 10.52 euros", Start:=i)

Range("A4").Value = str1


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: and what if A2 changes to "20 dollars"? OP is looking for a universal recalculation method.

Comment: @user1016274, no where OP specified for 'universal converter' sort of solution, only he asked to replace part of text string with other !!